Prove $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}1/n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\chi_{k/n}(A) <m(A)$
I study about Portmanteau Theorem and I would like to get some help.
I try to prove that $m_n = \lim\sup_{n\to\infty}1/n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\chi_{k/n}(A)$
$ <m(A)$ when $m$ is  lebesgue measure, I try to figure out an example that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}m_n(A)<m(A)$.
Thanks.
